# Display timer as well as "Pause / Resume / Stop" Button

Tags: vb.net, vba, vbscript, vb6

I have a small scrip that basically presses "F2" for me every 4 minutes for the duration of 8hours for the active application.

It works and is really basic as my skills in VB are extremely limited.

I now thought of a new addition to the project but have no idea if it is possible or how to tackle it.

I would basically like to have a small window in which the timer is displayed as well as a Pause and Resume and Stop button. It would be of a huge advantage if I could have these buttons as if I´m in another application, i don´t want the F2 button pressed.

Here is what I have:

```
Dim WshShell

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

dim ti
ti=timer

Do

WshShell.SendKeys "{F2}"

For AA = 1 To 9

  IF AA = 8 Then BB = "in  30 seconds"
  IF AA = 9 Then BB = "now !"

WScript.Sleep 30000

Dim oShell
Set oShell= CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
IF AA = 8 OR AA = 9 Then oShell.Popup " Refresh ... " & BB & " ",2,"Remind"

Next 

Loop while (timer-ti)<8*60*60

MsgBox "VB End: " & Time()
```

Thank you

Comment: Because I´m not sure WHO could assist ;)

Answer (score 1):

OK, just a high level answer as it's late and I'm going to bed.

On your form, place a timer control. Set it for a 1000 interval (1 sec).
Place your start & pause buttons also.
Here's the code that will run it.

```
Dim IsRunning As Boolean

Private Sub cmdPause_Click()
    IsRunning = False
End Sub

Private Sub cmdStart_Click()
    IsRunning = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    Static LastTime As Date
    If IsRunning Then
        If DateDiff("n", lastdate, Now()) >= 4 Then
            'sendkeys
            LastTime = Now()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The **IsRunning** variable is outside any procedure and is called a shared variable. Any procedure within this form can see it. The start & pause buttons turn the value of it to true or false.

The **Timer event** will run every sec. Here we're checking if IsRunning is true and also if 4 minutes has expired yet. If so, then you can run your sendkeys.

Comment: Pause won't really do anything other than delay the 'sendkeys until start is clicked again. However it's unclear what Haissam wants the pause to accomplish. This is probably the route I would go.

Comment: That's what I interpreted the OP wanted. A way to not send the keys while he was working in another program. A stop won't do anything a pause button doesn't already do. Or it could be made with just one button that both starts & stops the code. It should be enough to get him started.